# How do I have non 64k aligned private memory space?

Tags: windows, memory, virtual-memory, memory-management

In windows memory alignment granulatity is 64K, why do I have 4k on 0x7FFEF000?

Windows 10 PRO, 11763.316

[image]

Comment: Please include more details for your question

Comment: You didn't add nothing relevant to the question itself. Providing the Windows version is not enough.

Comment: @CaldeiraG I do not have any additional info, that could be relevant to this question. I do not understand why is this even possible, let alone have basic understanding what could be connected to this behavior.